# Insert differents elments in TableView [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I want to know how can you insert different elements in the same column of a tableView
in my view (FXML) I have a combobox which contains "person", a textfield to enter the person's number and a button and add these elements in  a Table View

FXML file

```
<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.3002754820936639" focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0">
 <items>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
       <children>
            <TableView fx:id="personnes" minWidth="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                 <columns>
                    <TableColumn prefWidth="200.0" text="Peronnes" fx:id="column">
                      <cellValueFactory>
                                        <PropertyValueFactory property="nom" />
                                    </cellValueFactory>
                                </TableColumn>
                              </columns>
                            </TableView>
                          </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                          <children>
                            <ComboBox fx:id="listPeronnes"  layoutX="25.0" layoutY="40.0" prefWidth="148.0">
                            </ComboBox>
                            <TextField fx:id="num" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="95.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
                            <Label layoutX="25.0" layoutY="78.0" prefWidth="66.0" text="numero" />
                            <Label layoutX="25.0" layoutY="14.0" prefWidth="66.0" text="Personnes" />
                            <Button onAction="#handleAdd"  layoutX="25.0" layoutY="121.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ajouter" />
                          </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                      </items>
                    </SplitPane>
```

So what I'm trying  to do is, when the user launches the application. He entered a number in the textfield, i have to insert this number in tableview, then if user want to insert another persone, but  by using combobox, he chose a person in combobox and add the name of this persone into tableView (so my Table View will contains Numbers and names (both string )

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;




public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    private Stage stage;

    @FXML
    protected ComboBox<Personnes> listPeronnes;
    @FXML
    protected TableView personnes;

    @FXML
    protected TableColumn column;

    @FXML
    protected TextField num;
    ObservableList<Personnes> liste = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Personnes("personne 1", 1),new Personnes("Personne 2",2));
    protected ListProperty<String> prs=new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList());



    @FXML
    protected void handleAdd()
    {       prs.add(num.getText());
        prs.add(listPeronnes.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getNom());
        personnes.getItems().setAll(prs);
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        listPeronnes.getItems().setAll(liste);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can't add different element type in the same column, but you can load and fxml with many things on your TableView. look at this http://fxexperience.com/2012/05/listview-custom-cell-factories-and-context-menus/ . your node on the tableview will be in your case the fxml with textfields, combobox ...

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will check that :)